# JavaScript updating window location using history.pushState

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have attached click event handler to an anchor tag `checkValid` which validates the element and calls the actual handler with a `setTimeout` of 0 [allowing the browser to go ahead with its execution].

```
//Code is just illustration
function checkValid() {
   if(valid) {
       setTimeout(reloadDiv, 0);
   }
}
    
function reloadDiv() {
  console.log(window.location.href);
}
```

The default handler for the same anchor tag changes the window location using `history.pushState`.

I expected that, because of `setTimeout(reloadDiv, 0)` I would be getting proper `window.location.href` as I'm scheduling my event to the end of queue.

But it is not happening. If I make `setTimeout` period to 500ms it works fine but this doesn't seem to remain constant across browsers and network speed. Is there a better way of getting the proper href url when a website uses `history.pushState`?

*Note:* I don't own the domain where my code is executing.

Comment: Could you please post both the pushState- and the event-listener-adding code, and how you access the foreign domain?

Comment: Hi Bergi, my script tag is loaded in the main document only not inside an iframe so I have access to top window. I use `addEventListener` to attach the event on the anchor tag. And the pushState code is owned by the publisher which I can't put up here

Comment: Okay, then the domain should not be a problem. Could you please post the code where the "default handler" is added? In which order are your handlers added?

Comment: I can't make any sure guess on order of handlers added and the default event is attached to that anchor tag by some yui plugin I hope and I couldn't find the source of it in the mess. But can you tell me how does the order of execution matters if I schedule it delayed?

Comment: It could be possible that each associated handler runs in its own execution context, and a delayed "thread" executes between them.

Comment: That can't be happening atleast in the case of javascript right?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think there's a spec saying that all event handlers have to execute in the same "thread".